# Bug in IE7 when refilling a <ul> list with JQuery : elements appearing below the previously hidden elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-7

In the following javascript script, I use the following code to empty an `<ul>` list of  countries and refill it (with a little animation using the hide() function of jquery).

It works in chrome and safari, but in IE, the new `<li>` elements of the `<ul>` are appearing behind the place of the previously showed `<li>`'s . Is there a workaround for this ?

```
        $('#country_list').hide(300,function(){
            var i;
            $(".country_list").empty();
            $(".country_list").height(0);
            $(".country_link").remove();
            $("#content").append('<div id="country_list_div" class="grid_3 "><ul id="country_list"></ul></div>');
            var country_list= country_dict[letter];
            var country_count = country_list.length;
            for (i=0;i<country_count;i++)
            {
                $("#country_list").append('<li><a class="country_link" href="" id="'+country_list[i][0]+'" na="'+country_list[i][1]+'">'+country_list[i][1]+"</a></li>");
            }

            $('#country_list').show(300);
            return false;
        });
```

Here is the corresponding html, as asked (You can see the whole thing at http://populationpyramid.net too)

```
       <div id="content" class="container_12">
        <div id="canvas_container_div" class="grid_7 " >
            <div id="canvas_container" ></div>
        </div>

        <div id="year_list_div" class="grid_1 " style="display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle;">
            <ul id="year_list">
            </ul>
        </div>

        <div id="alpha_list_div" class="grid_1 ">
            <div style="margin-left:11px;">
            <ul id="alpha_list">
            </ul>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="country_list_div" class="grid_3 ">
            <ul id="country_list">

            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Can you add some sample HTML so we can test this?  Some of the classes and ids might be associated with various elements.

Comment: I juste added the html + a link to the original page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why remove the original ul?  also you are removing ".country_list" not "#country_list"

Maybe...

```
$"#country_list").hide(300, function(){

  var cl = $(this); //get a variable handle
  cl.empty();
  var items = country_dict[letter];

  for (var i=0 i<items.length; i++) {
    cl.append(([
      '<li>'
        ,'<a class="country_link" href="javascript:void(0);"'
          ,' id="' + items[i][0] +'"'
          ,' na="' + items[i][1] + '"'
        ,'>'
          ,items[i][1]
        ,'</a>'
      ,'</li>'
    ]).join(''));
  }

  cl.show(300);

});
```

Comment: I did the array.join  thing because it's easier to visualize the markup via js that way... could combine this with a String.protoype.format extension or template add on.

Comment: It was the ".country_list" instead of "#country_list" thing. I have spent too much time on this, I don't have clear thoughts anymore. Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you specify the size (height or width) of the container, IE tends to flow its content opposed to overwrite positions. I always like to clip my containers to make sure they never flow out.